# Why UITable rows get unchecked everytime when i scroll in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have designed a Table view , For Select Followers list to send message,
so there I can select some followers and then send them message on twitter.

> I am using UITable View with UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark to make
>   this.

[image]

> But when I scroll down table, the checked rows get unchecked every
>   time.

I have decleard table view and an array for selected followers in **FollowersListView.h**

```
@interface FollowersListView : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{

IBOutlet UITableView *tableFollowers;

NSMutableArray *listFollowrsName;   
NSMutableArray *listSelectedFollowrsId;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *listFollowrsName;    
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *listSelectedFollowrsId;

@end
```

and my tableview code is like this in **FollowersListView.m** file

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [listFollowrsName count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"];
    //if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    //}

    NSString *cellValue = [listFollowrsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;    

    return cell;
}

//to select a row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];


    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;        
        NSLog(@"row is un-checked %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:path.row]);
        [listSelectedFollowrsId removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:path.row]];
        NSLog(@"Now selected person are%@",listSelectedFollowrsId);

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@"row is checked %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:path.row]);
        [listSelectedFollowrsId addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:path.row]];       
        NSLog(@"Now selected person are%@",listSelectedFollowrsId);
    }

}
```

I guess I need to load every cell as per the already stored selected list but not getting how to do.

Can anyone guide where I'm doing wrong,
Any help would be appreciated

**Edit**

@Novarg

I have declared "*listSelectedFollowrsId*" as a NSMutable Array in .h file and initialized in viewDidLoad method then adding/removing values in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method to manage selected rows.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you fetch twitter followers.....

Comment: @RDC i tried all possible things but getting selected elements hidden, when i scroll in table view, please do let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that you create a new cell every time that you scroll. The `if (cell == nil)` condition must be there, otherwise you will just keep on re-writing the cell over and over again.

Try the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
  }
  NSString *cellValue = [listFollowrsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;    
  return cell;
}
```

It might not work, I'm using a windows machine right now, so can't compile the code and test it myself now.

Hope it helps

***EDIT***

If it doesn't solve the problem I'd also add a variable(probably an `NSMutableDictionary`) to keep a record of the names that have been "checked". Using that you can add the following just before `return cell;` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if ([[theDictionary objectForKey:/*your key here, can be anything*/]isEqualToString:/*string or whatever, just make sure that the checked ones are different from the unchecked ones*/])
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

***EDIT 2***

Here's what you should add right before `return cell;`(didn't see the `listSelectedFollowrsId` array before):

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
for (int i = 0; i < [listSelectedFollowrsId count]; i++) {
  if ([[listSelectedFollowrsId objectAtIndex:i]intValue] == indexPath.row) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
}
```

That will set the accessory to checkmark if the row has been previously tapped.

Comment: @Novarg.. yeah this is the logic i wanted to know, and i have tried your solution but still not getting what i should store in dictionary where,, btw i stored selected row ids in a Mutable array [didSelectRowAtIndexPath] method, can you clear me PL?

Comment: yeah!! it works like a charm :) I really appreciate your help +1. give me a chance to help you too anytime cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{       

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];        
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];        
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;      
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;            
    }
    else
    {
        UIView *subview;
        while ((subview= [[[cell  contentView]subviews]lastObject])!=nil)       
            [subview removeFromSuperview];            
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [listFollowrsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/zip/J5Ok2vVe/DynamicApp_1_.html
i make a example for you you can take idea from the download this sample

Comment: on second tab you saw check and unchek funtionality

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you scroll the table, cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called.

In this function you are creating the cell again and again. So, your checkmarks are getting removed which you have marked in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Refer this [link](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) for detailed example of tableview.

Comment: thank you @apurv but the given link has simple list table but i want to do it with chekc or unchekc rows

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you are always setting it to unchecked. You need to test whether that row is in the your list of selected followers, if so set the accessory accordingly.

This is all due to cell reuse to keep memory consumption low even for tables with thousands of rows.